# C# reading from and writing to an excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I am having issues creating a class to read and write to an excel file. I need to read in the data from the file (only one column). Then I need to search the string input for square brackets [] and/or parentheses (). If the line contains those, I need to take the information inside those and separate (split) the answers by a forward slash (/). I keep getting errors with the splitting on the variables. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DataExcelApp
{
    public class ExcelApp
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            //make connection to document
            var fileName = string.Format("C:/Users/kbangert/Desktop/Karpel/ChargeLanguage.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

            //first query to document
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [ChargeLanguage] WHERE [description] != string.Empty", connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "descriptions");

            //DataTable data = ds.Tables["descriptions"];
            var data = ds.Tables["descript"].AsEnumerable();

            if (data != null)
            {
                var entry = data.ToString();
                var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
                var matches = Regex.Matches(entry, pattern);

                foreach (Match m in matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
                }

                string[] words = matches.Split('/');
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
            }
```

Comment: `I keep getting errors` what are they? Runtime exceptions? Compile errors? Where? What have you tried to fix the issues so far?

Comment: I keep getting an "Cannot resolve symbol - Split" error and it won't compile at all, even without the split portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
string[] words = matches.Split('/');
```

`matches` is a collection of `Match` objects. There's no `Split` method on that.

You probably want to do this:

```
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);

     string[] words = m.Groups[1].Value.Split('/');
     foreach (string word in words)
        Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Is there another way that I could go about filtering out the [] braces and () parentheses and split that up?

Comment: Does it work the way I wrote? If so, use this, because it's pretty straight forward. Of course you could write a regular expression that already captures things the way you want.

Comment: I get 2 errors - Error 2 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Replace' and no extension method 'Replace' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And Error - 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Not in the code you posted and not in the change I suggested, I assume. So for now I guess that my change works. :-)

Comment: It seems to be. Thank you!